# Catch button in controller

Tags: yii2

I have this form in view

```
<?php
    $form = ActiveForm::begin();
    $items = [201 => 'Тест', 202 => 'Тест2'];
    echo Html::dropDownList('list', 'null', $items);
?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?=
    Html::submitButton(
        'Удалить отмеченные',[
        'data' => ['confirm' => 'Вы действительно хотите перенести отмеченные товары в выбранную категорию?'],
        'name' => 'deleteProduct',
        'value' => 'delProduct', // добавить value
        'class' => 'btn btn-danger'
    ])
    ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

And this in controller

```
if (Yii::$app->request->post('deleteProduct'))
{
    $lk_number = $_POST['list'];

    print_r($lk_number);exit();
}
```

But when click on button there is no catch in controller. What I do wrong?

Comment: show the controller/action for the related  view  please

Comment: Is this your complete view? and complete code from the controller? Because using only this code it works fine with me.